# Switching workspace by using Super+Scroll Mouse is not available

Tags: 22.04, shortcut-keys, mouse, workspaces, navigation

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. The feature still worked fine until I installed the Nvidia drivers (not sure if it is the main reason). After the installation, I cannot use Super+Scroll mouse to switch workspaces, Although it is still available with Super+PageUp or PageDown
Is there any way to bring this feature back? Thanks a lot

EDIT: I have found out the problem and it definitely comes from Nvdia driver. I have removed the drivers and it work fine. However, I still want the solution to use this feature along with nvidia drivers. Thanks a lot

Comment: I have to have the mouse pointer over the grid-like icon ("show applications") in the activities task bar (i.e. the "program launcher"); there Super+Scroll works.

Comment: Yes, it is work. But this method seems inflexible because I need to spend time moving the mouse to the "Show applications" icon.

Comment: I'd say using the keyboard is more convenient than grabbing the mouse (scrollwheel or movement); hit Super begin typing "Settings" and click on/select the icon hit Enter, move to "Keyboard shortcuts" and type "workspace" in the looking glass field at the top -> Super+PgUp/PgDn. (in 20.04)